# How to change a function from forEach() to a function for working with one element JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to pure JS. I have a code like this, which when clicking on an element keeps the scroll position after reloading the page:

```
let cords = ['scrollX','scrollY'];
document.querySelectorAll('.scroll').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]);
    });
});
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
    if (localStorage[cords[0]]) {
        window.scroll(...cords.map(cord => localStorage[cord]));
        cords.forEach(cord => localStorage.removeItem(cord));
  }
});
```

But this is for the case when we have many elements with such a class. How can we change this function to work if we have only one instance of this class?

Thanks!

Comment: If the solution works for N elements, why won't it work for 1? What exactly is broken here?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I only have one button on the page, so I thought I'd better redo it.  There will be no performance difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Document.querySelectorAll() method returns an array of matching elements. Array.forEach() iterates through each item and performs an action, in this case a function which adds an event listener. This method should still work for an array with only one item.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I only have one button on the page, so I thought I'd better redo it.  There will be no performance difference?

Comment: No significant difference, but if you really want to know try 
`const button = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll');

button.addEventListener('click', () => { cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]);})})` This will make a constant of the button element and then add the event listener to it.